# Is it possible to filter by the range/sort key in Dynamodb?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I have a very simple 'tiny url' application where I take in urls and return an alias. I have a table defined like this:

```golang
    input := &dynamodb.CreateTableInput{
        AttributeDefinitions: []*dynamodb.AttributeDefinition{
            {
                AttributeName: aws.String("Alias"),
                AttributeType: aws.String("S"),
            },
            {
                AttributeName: aws.String("ExpiresAt"),
                AttributeType: aws.String("S"),
            },
        },
        KeySchema: []*dynamodb.KeySchemaElement{
            {
                AttributeName: aws.String("Alias"),
                KeyType:       aws.String("HASH"),
            },
            {
                AttributeName: aws.String("ExpiresAt"),
                KeyType:       aws.String("RANGE"),
            },
        },
        ProvisionedThroughput: &dynamodb.ProvisionedThroughput{
            ReadCapacityUnits:  aws.Int64(readCapacityUnits),
            WriteCapacityUnits: aws.Int64(writeCapacityUnits),
        },

        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
    }
```

The primary key is composite and is composed of an alias as the partition key and the expiry as the sort key.

My issue is I'm trying to query by the partition key and then filter by the sort key. The use case is trying to return the custom (alias) domain to redirect to as long as it hasn't expired.

This is my query:

```golang
    result, err := db.Query(&dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName:              aws.String(tableName),
        KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("#A = :alias AND :expires_at >= #T"),
        ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
            "#A": aws.String("Alias"),
            "#T": aws.String(time.Now().String()),
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            ":alias": {
                S: aws.String(alias),
            },
            ":created_at": {
                S: aws.String("ExpiresAt"),
            },
        },
        Limit: aws.Int64(1),
    })
```

I receive this problem:

```
ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element
    status code: 400, request id: 7c479115-7e3d-43ae-b94e-3fdf40cb3441
```

Now I understand I can setup a GSI but I'm wondering on a fundamental level if the sort key (ExpiresAt) can be used for this purpose. I also understand that I can setup a TTL on a per item basis but I don't think I've seen anything in the go SDK that makes that possible and I'd rather not go to the command line.

I should add that this is a learning exercise. Obviously, I can pull the row into memory and check the expiry manually but I want to understand the range key and really what its purpose is.

Based on reading through the dynamodb [book](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/querying/) I'm guessing it's a semantic error somewhere in my querying.

Thoughts?

**Edit**

I've presented a different way to query the fields and it seems to run into a different error.

```golang
    result, err := db.Query(&dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName:              aws.String(tableName),
        KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("#A = :alias AND #T >= ExpiresAt"),
        ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
            "#A": aws.String("Alias"),
            "#T": aws.String(time.Now().String()),
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            ":alias": {
                S: aws.String(alias),
            },
        },
        Limit: aws.Int64(1),
    })
```

This now returns:

```
ValidationException: Invalid condition in KeyConditionExpression: Multiple attribute names used in one condition
    status code: 400, request id: 2df7a659-0f5c-4609-a923-397a6e05b630
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got keys and values in `KeyConditionExpression` reversed. Try this,

```
result, err := db.Query(&dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName:              aws.String(tableName),
    KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("#A = :alias AND #E <= :expires_at"),
    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
        "#A": aws.String("Alias"),
        "#E": aws.String("ExpiresAt"),
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        ":alias": {
            S: aws.String(alias),
        },
        ":expires_at": {
            S: aws.String(time.Now().String()),
        },
    },
    Limit: aws.Int64(1),
})
```